# Python Detect Screensaver Start/Stop Event on Windows

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can a Python 2.7 script detect the start/stop event of a Windows Screensaver?

Comment: probably not ... but you can likely use win32api and/or wmi to find out if its currently active and poll it repeatedly

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do that with [Pywin32](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywin32). Pywin provides Python bindings for the Win32 API and for COM.

Regarding your question, it allows you to "listen" to windows events - such as start/stop event of a Windows ScreenSaver.

You should be able to get the current state of the screen saver by doing something like this:

```
import win32gui, win32con

def CheckScreenSaverState():
  return win32gui.SystemParametersInfo(win32con.SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING)
```

In this example we use the win32gui which allows access to the GUI of a windows application. By calling win32gui.SystemParametersInfo (which is a function that actually belongs to the windows GUI messaging system - out of scope for this explanation, read more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx)), we are able to get the state of the screen saver, using the SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING constant (which is an internal constant of the Windows OS). This method I wrote should return a boolean value of the state of the screen saver (True is running False if not).

I didn't have time to test it, but tell me how it went I might be able to help you further.

Good luck,
Tom.

Comment: Just wanted to say that I've tested this and it works on Windows 10.